# Overwrite argcheck method in python

Tags: python

I want to overwrite the argcheck method using _argcheck, but I haven't found out how it works. Does anyone know it?

I wrote it:

```
 def _argcheck(self, *args):
```

and I want to check if:

```
args[0]>0 , args[1]>2
```

because I created a new probability density function so I need to check the parameters but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: `if args[0] > 0 and args[1] > 2:`  Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Did you mean if I write that line in python?

Comment: Yep.  That's how [if](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) statements are done.

Comment: Yes,I know it,but what should I return?pass?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Just say `return args[0] > 0 and args[1] > 2`